# How to covert realmResult to array and pass to another activity?

Tags: java, android, realm

My program is to list a number of schools and when I click one school, it will list its students' name and ID.  And i am using Realm.

I am able to list the schools and covert the students result in realmResult, but I couldn't pass it to another activity.

I would like to convert the realmResult into array list and pass it to another activity with array adapter..Can anyone give me some clue to do it?.... Thanks.

```
public class School extends RealmObject {

@Required
private String SchoolID;
private String SchoolName;
private RealmList<Student> Students;

getters / setters 
}


public class Student extends RealmObject{

@Required
private String StudentID;
private String StudentName;

}
```

Main Activity
    .....

```
RealmResults<School> schools = realm.where(School.class).findAll();
    final SchoolAdapter adapter = new SchoolAdapter(this, R.id.schools_list, schools, true);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.schools_list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {


    RealmList list  = adapter.getRealmResults().get(position).getStudents();

    RealmResults test = list.where().findAll();
            ....
```

School Adapter

```
public class SchoolAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<School> implements ListAdapter {

private static class ViewHolder{
    TextView school;
}

public SchoolAdapter(Context context, int resId, RealmResults<School> realmResults, boolean automaticUpdate) {
    super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.school = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    School item = realmResults.get(position);
    viewHolder.school.setText(item.getSchoolName());
    return convertView;
}

public RealmResults<School> getRealmResults() {
    return realmResults;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your replies.  I think I didn't properly initialize the realm.

On the main activity:

```
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

On the student activity, I should have the following in the "On Create"

```
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily pass the SchoolID in a bundle to the next activity with your intent.

```
String someSchoolID = realmResults.get(position).getSchoolID();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNewActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putExtra(A_KEY, someSchoolID);
intent.setArguments(bundle);
intent.startActivity();
```

Retrieve the bundle and id in your **NEW** activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String someSchoolID;

if (extras != null) {
    someSchoolID = extras.getString(A_KEY);
}
```

and then fetch the actual school object like this:

```
School school = realm.where(School.class).equalTo("SchoolID",      
someSchoolID).findFirst();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Is there another way to get the object with the school ID..I could not retrieve the object because I am using realm in another activity...

Comment: the realm is single instance so you can use it in all activities, what error do you get?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I think I solve the problem.  I didn't properly initialize the realm...RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
        Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();